# (Rather than) as a conjunction

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions

It is said that, as a conjunction, the two constructions on each side of (rather than) must be parallel. So can this phrase join two sentences like this? (I know there are better ways of doing it)

> I will tell her rather than she tell me.

Comment: You're right -- it's not a good example. Your example is non-coordinative in that it has a comparative meaning, "in preference to".  The constituents are not syntactically alike, "I will tell her" being finite, "She tell me" non-finite. This being the case, "rather than" is not here a coordinator. Instead, "rather" is  an adverb.

Comment: Yes. And here's where the multi-word character of _rather than_ comes in handy; you can split them up and put _rather_ in an adverbial position: _I would rather tell her than she tell me._ Of course, there are better constructions, like _have her tell me_, as well.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler commented:

> Yes. And here's where the multi-word character of *rather than* comes in handy; you can split them up and put *rather* in an adverbial position: *I would rather tell her than she tell me.* Of course, there are better constructions, like *have her tell me*, as well.